# How to configure SAML on Grails 3.x

Tags: grails, saml, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

Can anyone advise how to run a Grails 3 app with SAML? I have a Grails 2.5 app running SAML using `spring-security-saml:2.0.0` but it doesn't support Grails 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently upgraded the G2 spring-security-saml plugin to be Grails 3 compliant.  Working with the original authors and have some additional testing to complete before uploading it to bintray.  It is currently working with my 3.0.9 applications.  I can send you the plugin project code of what I have completed so far.

Comment: Hi Jeff thanks for your response.  I'd be happy to try the plugin if you can share it thank you.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Can you fwd or advise how I may pull your plugin please, we're keen to get it going thanks!

Comment: I just got it finally completely tested you can find it at https://bintray.com/jeffwils/plugins/spring-security-saml  I have requested it be published with the grails 3 plugins.  Documentation is upcoming.  Reach out to me if you need some help.  Most of the configuration is the same as the 2.5 plugin so those docs can suffice for now.  You can also browse the source code on github at https://github.com/jeffwils/grails-spring-security-saml